# Wedding ring lost in bedroom

Tags: home

Can you find my ring that I dropped in my bedroom? I heard it hit the floor but I cannot find it anywhere. I have gotten on my hands and knees using a flashlight but have yet to find it.please help me

Comment: Hi user30313, Welcome to Lifehacks. Is there a possibility it rolled through a doorway into an adjacent room/closet?

Comment: no it was on a table at the side of my bed.  I heard it hit the floor but I can't find it.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't vacuum the room without covering the end of the tube with gauze or cheesecloth to catch your ring before it goes into the bag. Come to think of it, maybe that's the technique to use? I have known of a ring to roll quietly many feet away after hitting the floor. I have also found a coin leaning against the base of a bookshelf after being dropped by accident. Stuff happens. Good luck.

Comment: Get 100 rings. Drop them one at a time, Watch what happens. Then search again.